# Declaring a line in Visual Basic for CAD API

Tags: vb.net, vba, api, cad, solidworks

I am trying to declare a line and it's coordinates in the DraftSight API so that I can have it deleted from the drawing. In the code below, I have "line1" as an array with all of its xyz coordinates stored in it, and then I am using "line1.Erased" to delete this line. However, it is giving me the error "Erased is not a member of System.Array". So, does anyone know of another way I could properly declare "line1" while having its coordinates stored in it, so that the program will be able to recognize it and remove it from the drawing?   - Thanks so much!

```
    Dim startx, starty, startz, endx, endy, endz As Double
    startx = 1.125
    starty = 7.25
    startz = 0.0
    endx = 8.5
    endy = 7.25
    endz = 0.0

    Dim line1(startx, starty, startz, endx, endy, endz) As Object


    If True Then
        line1.Erased = True
    End If
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `Erase line1`? Erase is a method, not a boolean property.

Comment: @MacroMan   You are correct, but in this case I am not trying to clear an array and free up its memory. The goal here is to actually locate the line within a CAD drawing, designates its xyz coordinates, and delete it. "line1.Erased" is an internal command inside the APIs library. Which is of "Property Erased As System.Boolean". Thank you though!

Comment: Aah ok I understand - it's probably to do with your declaration then. When you declare a type with parentheses i.e. `Dim x() As Integer` it creates a `System.Array` of that data type with the dimensions supplied as arguments within the parentheses. I think perhaps you need something like `line1 = Array(startx, starty, ...)` to create a single dimension array, or you need to see if there's a custom type exposed by the API

Comment: The  `Dim line1(...)` line looks like you expect it to be a constructor call of some type, but it infact creates a multi-dimensional array of `object` if you want a line object of some type you would `dim line1(...) as new <sometype>`  (An object array has no erased property hence the error)